# How to make a macro that deep links to the Play Store app page?

Tags: google-play-store

My phone has an annoying app market, it redirected me to their store and automatically downloaded the app but I didn't click anything when I clicked on https://play.google.com links. I'm making a macro that redirects me to the Play Store when the app market is launched. I need to deep link the `play.google.com` link to Play Store, how can I do this?

Comment: You can try if the old `market` scheme is also redirected: `market://details?id=my.app.xyz`